# Where To Find Apache Spark Metrics For Operations?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, metrics, amazon-emr

I'm writing a paper in which I compare Apache Spark with Apache Hadoop for MapReduce algorithms.

In order to support my conclusion I use AWS EMR ~10 Nodes and Hashtagtrending as algorithm.

In Hadoop MapReduce I can get the avg. task time of map, reduce and shuffle tasks.

In Spark I'am using three operations flatMap,filter (map) and reduceByKey (reduce)

What is the best way to gather the same metrics as in Hadoop MapReduce ?
(total map time, total reduce time, total shuffle and sort time)